# Extract rows based on the condition and put in separate dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bin

Sample dataframes

df1

```
    A   B
0   7   5
1  20  10
2  12  15
3   4  14
4   3  19
```

df2

```
    A   B  A_bin  B_bin
0   5   3      1      1
1   8   4      2      1
2  10   8      2      2
3  11  13      3      3
4  20  18      4      4
```

Here ,df1 has the complete data ,df2 has the binning for the corresponding variables in df1.
if the bin value is 2 from bin columns in df2 i.e(A_bin , B_bin) it should extract the rows and put the rows in a separate dataframe.

I need new dataframes for all unique values of B.

```
    A   B  A_bin  B_bin
0   5   3      1      1
1   8   4      2      1
2  10   8      2      2
3  11  13      3      3
4  20  18      4      4
```

I want to do it without specifying the column name and indexes.

Comment: I don't understand.  Please try to explain better.

Comment: also provide what have you attempted so far

Comment: I don't see how `df1` is ever used?